Converting a PKCS8 PEM Private key to a RSAParameter in C#
I have a key in the format
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

I want to convert it to an RSA key to create a JWT from it. I'm using .NET 3.5 Framework.
But when I Use this code
PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(pem));
object key = pemReader.ReadObject();
//rsapri
RSAParameters rsaParameters = isPrivate ?
      DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)(((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)key).Private)) :
      DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaKeyParameters)key);
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

return rsa;

I get the error as
InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair'.' 
I realized since the Private Key that I have is in PKCS8 and not PKCS1 format.
Is there a way to convert the PKCS8 to RSA?

Parameters and keys are not the same type object : (RsaKeyParameters)key.  You cannot create a parameter from a key.

The code seems to work and throws no error when I have a private key that says
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

For a private PKCS#8 key, pemReader.ReadObject() returns a reference to an RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters object. Therefore try RSAParameters rsaParameters = isPrivate ? DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)key) : ....

I tried this out and it's creating the RSAParameter, but when I run rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters) it throws 'Bad Data' Exception.
I don't know what could be wrong with my Private Key, seems to look fine.

I figured out that the Nuget version of Bouncy Castle is not up to date with their github and it does not add correct padding.
